# Center bootstrap col-xs-* class (centering bootstrap fixed width input bot)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

I am trying to center a bootstrap input field within a column div but none of the methods I've tried seems to work.

What I've tried so far:

```
<div data-role="page" id="add-host" class="container">
      <div class="default-template">
              <h1>Enter the information about the host</h1>
                <div class="col-xs-4 center-block">
                    <input type="date" id="host_name" value="" required="" />
              </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried the class text-center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are potentially many ways you could do this: using the grid or with no grid at all, using bootstrap form classes or not. If you're using the grid you should use an offset if possible. Column Offsetting [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)

Working Examples:

```css
/*#4 */

.input-control {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-info">#1 Using the Grid with Bootstrap Form Classes</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="default-template">
      <h1 class="text-center">Enter the information about the host</h1>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" value="" required="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-info">#2 Using the Grid without Bootstrap Form Classes</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="default-template text-center">
      <h1>Enter the information about the host</h1>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
        <input type="date" value="" required="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-info">#3 Not Using the Grid without Bootstrap Form Classes</div>
  <div class="default-template text-center">
    <h1>Enter the information about the host</h1>
    <input type="date" value="" required="" />
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-info">#4 Not Using the Grid but With Bootstrap Form Classes</div>
  <div class="default-template">
    <h1 class="text-center">Enter the information about the host</h1>
    <input type="date" class="form-control input-control" value="" required="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: using the first one, it worked! seemed the order I put my divs in was also mucking things up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
  <input type="date" id="host_name" value="" required="" />
</div>
```

or

```
<center>
  <input type="date" id="host_name" value="" required="" />
</center>
```

Comment: doesn't work, only centers the text inside the button, not the button its self.

Comment: try `<center><input type="date" id="host_name" value="" required="" /></center>`

Comment: Nope neither worked, using <center> made it an even bigger mess. :/ I'm using jquerry mobile and bootstrap mobile which might be why

Comment: I tried both `text-center` and `center`. Both works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use: center? It is responsible and it centers everything.

```html
<center><input type="date" id="host_name" value="" required="" /> </center>
```

Comment: it does not, it just puts the <h1> inside the text box and makes a huge mess.

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom class, say `myClass` to your `col-xs-4` div like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 center-block myClass">
    <input type="date" id="host_name" value="" required="" />
</div>
```

Then add this to your css:

```
.myClass {  
   text-align:center;
}
.myClass input {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Link to jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e0d8my79/119/

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to center the button within the `col-xs-4` div, then you should be able to do it by using text-center class (if `#host_name` has `display:inline-block`), or using `margin:0 auto` (if `#host_name` has `display:block`)

if you are trying to center the button relative to the whole page, you can try removing the `col-xs-4` class then set the div's width to what you need and use `margin:0 auto`